# Javascript call back function not working as expected. Trying to make sure all code is complete before the finalization logic is executed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I am trying to have a summary section in my website that will take all the results from other functions and display the information. I created the following functions and call path to try and get this but it appears that the callback is still being called before the largest function finishes.

```
Office.onReady(info => {
 
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
    
    mainprocessing(finalization);
  }
});

function mainprocessing(callback){
  console.log("main processing")
    reviewEmailInfo();
    attachmentCheck();
    checkBodyforLinks();
    checkmsgforriskywords();
    callback();
}

function finalization(){
  console.log("entering finalization");
  document.getElementById("riskscore").innerHTML = "This email has a riskscore of " + riskScore;
}
```

I put console.logs into each function at the beginning and end and this is what is in the logs

```
main processing taskpane.js:43 
entering review email taskpane.js:122 
entering attachment check taskpane.js:137 
leaving attachment check taskpane.js:174 
entering check body taskpane.js:192 
leaving check body taskpane.js:196 
entering check risky words taskpane.js:210 
entering leaving check risky taskpane.js:38 
entering finalization VM72 taskpane.js:9931 
leaving review email VM72 taskpane.js:9002 
[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.client:52 
[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
leaving review email taskpane.js:106


function checkBodyforLinks(){
  console.log("entering check body");
 Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
    "html",
    { asyncContext: "This is passed to the callback" },
    function callback(result) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var bodyHtml = parser.parseFromString(result.value, "text/html");
        //need to add check to ignore mailto: links
        var linkDomains = [], links = bodyHtml.links;
        document.getElementById("linkCheck").innerHTML = "No links found within email body";
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
          linkDomains.push(links[i].href);
        }
        if (linkDomains.length > 0){
          document.getElementById("linkCheck").innerHTML = "There are " + links.length+1 +"links in the email body";
        }
      }
    );
    console.log("leaving check body");
  }

console.log("entering review email");
  Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(
    function(asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            var headers = asyncResult.value;     
            var ReplyTo = headers.replace(" ","").match(/Return-Path:(.*)/);
            if (ReplyTo.length != null){
              var cleanEmail = ReplyTo[1].substring(1,ReplyTo[1].length); 
              if(cleanEmail == Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress){
                document.getElementById("reply-match").innerHTML= "The from and reply email address match";
              }else{
                riskScore += 5;
                document.getElementById("reply-match").innerHTML= "The from and reply email address DO NOT MATCH. The sender is:" + Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress + "  and the reply addres is: " + cleanEmail;
              }
            }
           var ARCAuthResult = headers.replace(" ","").match(/ARC-Authentication-Results:(.*)/);
           var dkimChk = false;
           var spfChk = false;
           if(ARCAuthResult != null){
             if(ARCAuthResult[1].search("spf=pass")){
               spfChk = true;
             }
             if(ARCAuthResult[1].search("dkim=pass")){
               dkimChk = true;
             }
           }else{
             var AuthResult = headers.replace(" ","").match(/Authentication-Results:(.*)/);
             if(AuthResult.length != null){
               if(AuthResult[1].search("spf=pass")){
                 spfChk = true;
               }
               if(AuthResult[1].search("dkim=pass")){
                 dkimChk = true;
               }}}
            if(spfChk == true & dkimChk==true){
                 document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "Both DKIM and SPF are safe";
            }else if(spfChk == true){
              riskScore += 5;
                 document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "DKIM check failed";
            }else if(dkimChk == true){
              riskScore += 5;
                 document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "SPF check failed";
            }else{
              riskScore += 10;
                 document.getElementById("dkimspfchk").innerHTML = "SPF amd DKIM check failed";
            }

            //Check for domain match between sender and reciever
            var domainIndex = Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress.indexOf("@");
            var senderDomain = Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress.slice((domainIndex+1), Office.context.mailbox.item.sender.emailAddress.length);
            var receiverAddress = headers.replace(" ","").match(/To:(.*)/);
            if (receiverAddress.length != null){
              domainIndex = receiverAddress[1].indexOf("@");
              var recieverDomain = receiverAddress.slice((domainIndex+1),receiverAddress.length-1);

              if(senderDomain == recieverDomain){
                document.getElementById("domainMatch").innerHTML = "This email comes from with your domain";
             }else {
                riskScore += 1;
                document.getElementById("domainMatch").innerHTML = "This message comes from an external email address";
                console.log("risk score after domain " + riskScore);
              }
              }
              //var domainAge = domainWhois(senderDomain);
              console.log("leaving review email");
            return;         
        } else {
            if (asyncResult.error.code == 9020) {
                // GenericResponseError returned when there is no context.
                // Treat as no context.
            } else {
                console.log("error");
              }
          }
      }
  );
  return;
}
```

Comment: If those other functions are asynchronous then that's expected. Just adding a callback doesn't magically make the other functions synchronous, you still have to wait for them to finish. We need to see their code to tell how to do that (specifically the ones that log the "leaving review email" texts because they seem to be the ones that are asynchronous.)

Comment: Agreed, a _lot_ of things in the Office API are asynchronous. From the names of the functions you're calling, it's a good guess that some of them are async. For example, getting the message body or the to/cc/bcc are all async.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I have uploaded two of the sections. I made the assumption that even if an async call was in these it would still want for it to finish.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I have added two of the functions to show what is occurring in it. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Yeah, that's where you ran into trouble. When your checkBodyforLinks() function calls Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(), the code in checkBodyforLinks does not wait for the async operation to complete. Your function returns immediately, and then some time later the callback runs. So when your function returns, none of the important work it does has happened yet. Instead of running your various `checkXyz` functions all in a row, you need to put code in each callback function to call the next one of your functions in sequence.

Comment: Here are a couple of references for you: [Asynchronous programming in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/asynchronous-programming-in-office-add-ins) and [Get, set, or add recipients when composing an appointment or message in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-set-or-add-recipients). See also some related pages listed in the "Compose scenario" section of the sidebar for the latter page.